# I need help writing a basic return decimal from string function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have scoured the web for an hour-and-a-half looking for a working, simple string-to-decimal function, and have been depressingly failed. The mentioned string is comprised of letters and numbers. This is meant for a cipher. I would like something like this...

```
function ConvertDec(str){
    //do conversion
    return decVal;    
}
```

Were it would be used as such...

```
decSeed = ConvertDec(seed);
decUserString = ConvertDec(strVal);
```

These values would then be multiplied to get a full value, which would later be decrypted.

Comment: have you tried parseFloat() ?

Comment: You can do any mathematic operation other than "+" to convert a string to decimal, e.g. `"1" * 1` returns a Number, or trivially `+'1'` ([unary `+`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6)) returns a Number too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the basics

```
var str = "123.45";
var dec = parseFloat(str);

console.log(dec); // 123.45
```

[Read more about `parseFloat` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: Or `var dec = +str;`. :-)